# How to make a jump like effect for object in unity 3d?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, physics

I have an object which is placed on the ground.
when i press "space" key it hast to jump and fall down on the ground.
to fall it down i am using gravity with rigid body.
i attached it to boxcollider of the ground so that it can detect 
when is on ground and air through OnTriggerEnter() and OnTriggerExit() respecitvely.
the code is follows:-

```
#pragma strict

var jumping:boolean=false;//when the body is in air that is still jumping
var grounded:boolean=true;//laid on ground
var body: Rigidbody;
function Start () 
{
body = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function Update () {


if(Input.GetKey("up")){transform.Translate(-3*Time.deltaTime,0,0);}
if(Input.GetKey("left")){transform.Translate(0,0,-3*Time.deltaTime);}

if(Input.GetKey("right")){transform.Translate(0,0,3*Time.deltaTime);}

if(Input.GetKey("down")){transform.Translate(3*Time.deltaTime,0,0);}

if(Input.GetKey("space"))
{
jumping=true;
if(grounded && jumping)
{
body.AddForce(transform.up*5);
}
}
}


//On the ground
function OnTriggerEnter()
{
grounded=true;jumping=false;
body.useGravity=false;
}
//On the  ground
function OnTriggerStay()
{
body.useGravity=false;
grounded=true;jumping=false;
}
//jumping
function OnTriggerExit()
{
body.useGravity=true;
grounded=false;jumping=false;
}
```

but it is not jumping,instead it goes up for while and fall down contineously. eventhough useGravity becomes false it continues to fall down.

what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with ForceMode. You don't define it, so it defaults to `Force` but you need `Impulse` for a jump like effect.

[Here's a link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) to the documentation for a better understand.

Comment: Yeah you are right. i changed Forcemode to VelocityChange.
 i.e 
body.AddForce(transform.up*5,ForceMode.VelocityChange);
that is fine.
but it falls down contineously eventhough usegravity becomes falls.

Comment: The layout should be wrong (e.g. too thin "ground" collider). Add debug.log events inside your calls to see what's going on.

Comment: I increased the collider size,didn't worked.
my idea was the object should stop falling when the variable body.useGravity=false;  
so,when it become false it continues to fall down.

Comment: Thanx bro Working fine now.